# A closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\Gamma^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, factorial, gamma-function

I am looking for a closed form of the following series

> \begin{equation}
> \mathcal{I}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\Gamma^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)
> \end{equation}

I have no idea how to answer this question. Wolfram Alpha gives me result:

> $$\mathcal{I}\approx2.7415567780803776$$

Could anyone here please help me to obtain the closed form of the series preferably (**if possible**) with elementary ways (high school methods)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the sum starts by $k=0$? The $\Gamma$ function has a pole in $0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, it should be started from $k=1$. Edited! >_<

Comment: Multiplying and dividing each term by $\bigg(\dfrac k2\bigg)^2$, and using the fact that $x~\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)=x!$, we have $I=-4\cdot\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\displaystyle{k\choose k/2}~k^2}$ . At the same time, we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\big(2x\big)^{2k}}{\displaystyle{2k\choose k}~k^2}=2\arcsin^2x$.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the identity given by the Euler Beta function
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \,dx=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
to state:
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\Gamma(k/2)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x(1-x)\right)^{k/2-1}\,dx $$
and by switching the series and the integral:
$$ S = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{x(1-x)})}{x(1-x)}dx = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{x(1-x)})}{x(1-x)}dx,$$
$$ S = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\log(1+\sqrt{1/4-x^2})}{1/4-x^2}dx = 4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2})}{1-x^2}dx,$$
$$ S = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta.$$
Now Mathematica gives me $\frac{5\pi^2}{18}$ as an explicit value for the last integral, but probably we are on the wrong path, and we only need to exploit the identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2\binom{2k}{k}}=\frac{\pi^2}{18}$$
that follows from the Euler acceleration technique applied to the $\zeta(2)$-series. The other "piece" (the $U$-piece in the Marty Cohen's answer) is simply given by the Taylor series of $\arcsin(z)^2$. More details to come.

---

As a matter of fact, *both* approaches lead to an answer. 
The (Taylor) series approach, as Bhenni Benghorbal shows below, leads to the identity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\Gamma^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)x^k= 2 \arcsin \left( x/2 \right)  \left(\pi - \arcsin \left( x/2\right)  \right),\tag{1}$$
while the integral approach, as Achille Hui pointed out in the comments, leads to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta&=&\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(1+\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-t^3)-\log(1-t)-\log(1+t^2)}{t}\,dt\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\frac{2}{3}\log(1-t)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+t)}{t}\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4+3(-1)^k}{k^2}=\frac{1}{6}\left(4-\frac{3}{2}\right)\zeta(2)=\frac{5\pi^2}{72}.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2}$$

Thanks to both since now this answer may become a reference both for integral-log-ish problems like $(2)$ and for $\Gamma^2$-series like $(1)$.

---

**Update 14-06-2016**. I just discovered that [this problem can also be solved by computing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826309/integral-involving-legendre-polynomial-and-xn/1826339#1826339) 
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} x^n\, P_n(x)\,dx, $$
where $P_n$ is a Legendre polynomial, through Bonnet's recursion formula or Rodrigues' formula. Really interesting.

Comment: Nice use of the Beta function. I didn't think of that when I did my "answer".

Comment: The next question is: how to calculate the integral? Thanks anyway for your answer (>‿◠)✌

Comment: @V-Moy Let $t = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, we have
$$
  4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(1+\frac12\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta
= 4\int_0^1\log(1+\frac{t}{1+t^2})\frac{dt}{t}\\
= 4\int_0^1( \log(1-t^3) - \log(1-t)-\log(1+t^2) )\frac{dt}{t}\\
= -\frac23\int_0^1 (4\log(1-t) + 3\log(1+t))\frac{dt}{t}\\
= \frac23 \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{4+3(-1)^k}{k}t^{k-1} \right) dt\\
= \frac23 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4+3(-1)^k}{k^2}
= \frac23 \left( 4 - 3\left(1 - \frac{2}{2^2}\right)\right)\zeta(2)
= \frac{5\pi^2}{18}
$$

Comment: @achillehui I wish you were a 14 y.o. boy, we could be a best friend (or boyfriend) （★´−｀）人（´▽｀★） *kidding

Comment: @achillehui It seems Anna (eventually) has found the general formula of the integral you've calculated in her own post http://math.stackexchange.com/a/995449/146687

Comment: saw this answer a few hours ago and could apply it immediately (+1)

Answer (score 9):

$($This is more of a comment than an answer, but $...)$

> *Consider the even and odd $k$ in separate sums:*

**Note:** You probably do not want $\Gamma(0)$ in the sum, so I'll start at $k=1$.

> $$\begin{align}
> \\S
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right]^2
> \\\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k)!}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{2k}{2}\right)\right]^2
> ~+~\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2k+1+1}}{(2k+1)!}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)\right]^2
> \\\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{(2k)!}\left[\Gamma\left(k\right)\right]^2
> ~+~\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\left[\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)\right]^2
> \\\\
> &=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{((k-1)!)^2}{(2k)!}
> ~+~\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(2k)!}{4^kk!}\right]^2
> \\\\
> &=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{((k-1)!)^2}{(2k)!}
> ~+~\pi\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+1)16^k(k!)^2}
> \\\\
> &=-T~+~\pi~U,
> \\\\
> \end{align}$$

where $~T=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{((k-1)!)^2}{(2k)!},~$ and $~U=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+1)16^k(k!)^2}.$

You can write these sums in terms of the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $\displaystyle\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2},$ 
 and people who know more about these than I can possibly sum these.

I'll leave it at this.

Comment: I did too split the series into odd and even part, but it's still hard for me to obtain the closed form. Thanks anyway for your answer (>‿◠)✌

Comment: Your solution is nice and was very inspiring ! Cheers :)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀: We have $$T ~=~ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\displaystyle{2k\choose k}k^2} ~=~ \frac{\pi^2}{18},$$ see my comment on the main post, and $$U ~=~ \sum_{k=0}^\infty{2k\choose k}\frac{16^{-k}}{2k+1} ~=~ \frac\pi3,$$ which follows from the well-known [Taylor series of the arcsine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a closed form

> $$ \mathcal{I}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\Gamma^2\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)x^k= 2 \arcsin \left( x/2 \right)  \left(\pi - \arcsin \left( x/2\right)  \right) .$$

Now just plug in $x=1$ and the result follows.

Comment: How to get it? Could you elaborate Mr. Mhenni Benghorbal?

Comment: @V-Moy: You can use Maple to get this cloded form.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment that an answer

As Jack D'Aurizio commented, I suppose that the summation starts at $k=1$ and not $k=0$ as written in the post. Using a CAS, the result obtained is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right]^2=\frac{5 \pi ^2}{18}$$ which matches the value you obtained using Wolfram Alpha. Obtaining this result with elementary ways (such as high school methods) seems difficult (at least to me).

The only thing I have been able to obtain is that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right]^2=\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(1,\frac{n}{2}+1,\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2},\frac{n}{2}+2; \frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (n+3)}-\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(1,\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{n}{2}+1,\frac{n
   }{2}+\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (n+2)}+\frac{5 \pi ^2}{18}$$ which is neither nice, neither easy to obtain.

One small thing I did was to compute the sum for odd and even terms. For odd values of $k$ the infinite sum is $\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$ while for even values of $k$ the infinite sum is $-\frac{\pi ^2}{18}$ and this makes the final result of $\frac{5\pi ^2}{18}$.

**Added later**

Looking at Marty Cohen's answer, and computing the terms he defined, I found that $T=\frac{\pi ^2}{18}$ and $U=\frac{\pi}{3}$ which again lead to the same final result.

Comment: I remember to have seen similar series (the one that follows from the Euler acceleration techniques) in many papers that deal with the irrationality measure of $\pi^2$. The part corresponding to odd values of $k$ (central binomials in the numerator) depends on the Taylor series of the arcsine square, while the part corresponding to even values of $k$ is a rational multiple of $\zeta(2)$ by applying the right change of variables in the integral $\int_{[0,1]^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{1-xy}=\zeta(2)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. This is a very interesting comment. Thanks !

Comment: Mr. Claude Leibovici: The term 'elementary ways' in my dictionary means without involving residues or hypergeometric function, but thank you for your answer. Cheers! (>‿◠)✌

Comment: My knowledge (or lack of it) usually limits me to moderately elementary methods. I'm glad that I did not make any mistakes in my manipulations.

Comment: @V-Moy. I know and I wrote it in my answer ! If I wrote the partial sum, it was to show the complexity that I was unable to overcome. Fortunaly, Marty Cohen and Jack D'Aurizio provided interesting solutions. Cheers :)