# Question regarding Basel Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, contest-math, education

I have the following problem as quoted in a book: $$ S=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots $$
Prove that: $$ S < 3 $$
I know that $ S $ evaluates to $ \frac{\pi^2}{6} $, so it is absolutely true. But I have no idea how to prove it. Also, the author of the book wants the proof without having the knowledge of the sum of the given infinite series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can get an even tighter bound, albeit presumably with a different method than intended -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726187/sum-of-reciprocals-of-squares-bounding

Comment: Thanks Eevee but can I get a simpler proof that S < 2 ?

Comment: The second answer to the linked question has a pretty dang simple proof at the beginning.

Comment: I find it interesting that this question has several approaches that easily show $S < 2$.  It makes me curious if there's an even easier approach that shows $S < 3$, as OP asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let’s start with $n(n+1)\gt n^2\gt n(n-1)$. This means

$${1\over n(n+1)}\lt {1\over n^2}\lt {1\over n(n-1)}$$

Now use $1/n(n+1)=1/n-1/(n+1)$ and $1/n(n-1)=1/(n-1)-1/n$ to get assuming the series converge and because the sums telescope.

$$\begin{align}
{1\over 1}-{1\over 2}&\lt {1\over 1^2}\leq 1\\
{1\over 2}-{1\over 3}&\lt {1\over 2^2}\lt {1\over 1}-{1\over 2}\\
{1\over 3}-{1\over 4}&\lt {1\over 3^2}\lt {1\over 2}-{1\over 3}\\
&\vdots\\
{1\over n}-{1\over n+1}&\lt {1\over n^2}\lt {1\over n-1}-{1\over n}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

One gets eventually

$$1\lt S\lt 2$$

Comment: A nice brilliant proof I was looking for!

Comment: Nice. Using $n^2>n^2-1$ gives a better bound using similar telescoping. +1

Answer (score 2):

This proof is overkill, but nevertheless fun.

For every $x\in(-1,0)$, it can be shown that $\ln(1+x)<x$. Since $-1<-1/n^2<0$ is true for every $n>1$, it follows that

$$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)<-\frac{1}{n^2}$$

This is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{n^2}<-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

from which we deduce that

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2} &= 1+\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&< 1+\sum_{n=2}^{k}-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\
&= 1-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\ln\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)\\
&= 1-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln\left((n+1)(n-1)\right)-\ln\left(n^2\right)\right]\\
&= 1-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln(n+1)+\ln(n-1)-2\ln(n)\right]\\
&= 1-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)+\ln(n-1)-\ln(n)\right]\\
&= 1-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\right]-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln(n-1)-\ln(n)\right]\\
&= 1-\left[\ln(k+1)-\ln(2)\right]+\sum_{n=2}^{k}\left[\ln(n)-\ln(n-1)\right]\\
&= 1-\ln(k+1)+\ln(2)+\ln(k)-\ln(2-1)\\
&= 1+\ln(2)-\left[\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\right]\\
&= 1+\ln(2)-\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)
\end{align}

Now, $\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, so the sum of the series is at most $1+\ln(2)$. We can then conclude that the sum is strictly less than $2$ (and hence $3$) by leveraging the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x$ once more.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq 1+\ln(2) = 1+\ln(1+1) < 1+1=2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$S=1+\frac14+\frac19+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots$$
Then we have: $$4S=4+1+\frac49+\frac14+\frac{4}{25}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots\\=S+4(1+\frac19+\frac{1}{25}+\cdots)\\<S+4(1+\frac14+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+...)\\=S+4(1+\frac S4)$$

Then $$4S<S+4(1+\frac S4)\implies S<2$$

The third line inequality holds because $\frac14>\frac19, \frac{1}{16}>\frac{1}{25}$, etc...

Comment: A very nice approach indeed!