# Elementary solution of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-3x+x^2)\ln x}xdx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Is there a **elementary** way to evaluate
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-3x+x^2)\ln x}xdx=\frac85\zeta(3)+\frac{2}{5} \pi ^2 \ln\varphi-2 i \pi\ln^2\varphi$$
>   where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio?

(I posted it as [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973352/521015))
Factorizing $1-3x+x^2$ gives $1-3x+x^2=(x-\varphi^2)(x-\varphi^{-2})$, use the formula
$$\tiny\int\frac{\ln(x-a)\ln x}{x}dx=\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\ln x \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2x \ln \left(1-\frac{x}{a}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \ln ^2x \ln (x-a)+C$$
and use
$$\operatorname{Li}_3(\varphi^2)=\frac45 \zeta (3)-\frac 23 \ln ^3\varphi-2 i \pi  \ln ^2\varphi+\frac{8}{15} \pi ^2 \ln\varphi$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_3(\varphi^{-2})=\frac45 \zeta (3)+\frac 23 \ln ^3\varphi-\frac{2}{15} \pi ^2 \ln\varphi$$
we can deduce the result.
Can it be done without using the value of $\operatorname{Li}_3$?

Comment: Is there an iota in the answer?

Comment: No, $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: That is what iota is called

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389425/a-very-odd-looking-statement-about-zeta3-and-textli-2-left-frac1-va

Comment: What is your definition of logarithm in you computation?

Comment: The main branch of $\operatorname{Ln}$, i.e. $\Im\ln x\in(-\pi,\pi]$.