# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{{2k \choose k}}=2+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: summation

Using tha integral representation of the reciprocal of the binomial co-efficient:
$${n \choose j}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_{0}^{1} x^j (1-x)^{n-j}~ dx,~~~~(1)$$
here, we state and prove an interesting sum that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{{2k \choose k}}=2+\frac{\pi}{2}~~~~~~(2)$$
Proof:
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  2^{k}{2k \choose k}^{-1}= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2k+1)~ [2x(1-x)]^{k}$$
Using $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2k+1)r^k=\frac{1+r}{(1-r)^2},$ we can write
$$S=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+2x(1-x)}{(2x^2-2x+1)^2} dx =\int_{0}^{1} \left (\frac{2}{(2x^2-2x+1)^2} -\frac{1}{2x^2-2x+1} \right)dx $$
The first integral in above has been obtained by assuming $$\int \frac{2}{(2x^2-2x+1)^2}dx=\frac{Ax+B}{2x^2-2x+1},$$ then by differentiation, we find $A=2, B=-1$.
$$\implies S=\left(\frac{2x-1}{2x^2-2x+1}-\tan^{-1}(1-2x)\right)_{0}^{1}=2+\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

The question is: how to prove this using other approaches?

Comment: what is your  question?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the question: How to sum it otherwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Lucian's comment is particularly insightful]? [Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548563/calculate-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac12k-choose-k)

Comment: More explicitly: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2496325 seems to be an exact duplicate.