# Short way to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\ln(\frac{a-x^2}{a+x^2})\cdot\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to evaluate this integral, $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(\frac{a-x^2}{a+x^2}\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

An approach:
1. Using integration by parts

$u=\ln\left(\frac{a-x^2}{a+x^2}\right)$, $du=\frac{x^2+a}{x^2-a}\left[\frac{2x}{a+x^2}+\frac{2x(a-x^2)}{a+x^2}\right]dx$

$dv=\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, $v=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

$$I=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2+a}dx-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2-a}dx=2I_1-2I_2$$

Integral $I_1$: Make a substitution of: $x=\sin(v)$, $v=\arcsin(x)$, $dx=\cos(v)dv$

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(v)}{a+\sin^2(v)}dv$$

Using trig to rewrite: $$I_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sec^2(v)\frac{dv}{[1+\tan^2(v)][(a+1)\tan^2(v)+a]}$$

Make another substitiution of: $v=\tan(y)$, $dy=\frac{1}{\sec^2(v)}dv$ and using partial fraction decomp:

$$I_1=(a+1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{a+(a+1)y^2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=(a+1)I_3-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

With this substitution: $t=\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{\sqrt{a}}y$, $dy=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+1}}dt$

$$I_3=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a(a+1)}}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{\sqrt{a}}-1\right)$$

In the same manner, $$I_2=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a-1}}{\sqrt{a}}-1\right)$$

Finally, $$I=\pi\left(\frac{\sqrt{a-1}-\sqrt{a+1}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)$$

I am looking for another short approach of evaluating integral $I$

Comment: While in your question, your formatting is fine, please don't format in a way that makes the vertical distance of a title to large.

Comment: Congratulations for the patience you show ! Good job, indeed and $+1$

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $a>1$, the original integral equals
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{a-x}{a+x}\right)\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{arctanh}(x/a)}{x\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx \tag{1}$$
or
$$ -\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n-1/2}}{(2n+1)a^{2n+1}\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\pi\binom{4n}{2n}}{(2n+1)16^n a^{2n+1}}\tag{2}$$
hence it is enough to recall the generating function for [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) to recover the wanted identity.

---

It is worth noticing that [the Maclaurin series of the squared arcsine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878477/a-closed-form-of-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k1k-gamma2-left-frack2/878499#878499) allows to compute the similar integral
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2-x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{\color{red}{x}\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$
or the hypergeometric function $\phantom{}_4 F_3\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,1;\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{5}{4},\tfrac{3}{2};z\right)$ in terms of $\arcsin^2$ and $\text{arcsinh}^2$, in a very similar and efficient way.

Comment: Nice answer +1. Do you think you could do the integral by treating $a$ as a parameter and differentiating under the integral sign?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin: of course, that is exactly what the OP did, but known GFs shorten the path to the solution really much.

Comment: How do you mean? The OP used integration by parts?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin: all right, I was inaccurate. What I really meant to say is that using Feynman's trick works, indeed, but it just produces very similar integrals to the ones managed by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Under $x\to\sin x$, one has
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(\frac{a-x^2}{a+x^2}\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{a-\sin^2x}{a+\sin^2x}\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^2x}.$$
Let
$$I(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{a-k\sin^2x}{a+k\sin^2x}\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^2x}$$
and then
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(k)&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(-\frac1{a-k\sin^2x}-\frac1{a+k\sin^2x}\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=&-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{a(a+k)}}+\frac1{\sqrt{a(a-k)}}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ I=I(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt a}\int_0^1\left(\frac1{\sqrt{a+k}}-\frac1{\sqrt{a-k}}\right)\mathrm dk=-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt a}(\sqrt{a+1}-\sqrt{a-1}).$$